# Consume dll from php wamp

Tags: php, dll

I have been given 2 dll's.
The first encrypts a string.
The second, decrypts an encrypted string.

I do not know how it works this dll.

Also I have been given a code example in .net (Don't know .net)

```
dll_decrypt_.Decrypt myuser = new dll_decrypt.Decrypt();

user = myuser.DecryptString(userEncrypted);
```

I have searched among the web, but still cant' find the answer.
Also I have added the 2 dll's to the ext folder in wamp:

> C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.32\ext

And added the "extension=dll_decrypt.dll" into the php.ini file both in apache and php folders.

This would be my php code:

```
try

{

$dll = new COM('dll_decrypt.Decrypt');

$dll->Function();

}

catch(Exception $e)

{

echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage(), "\n";

}
```

I expect to get the decrypted string so I can see the user.